# Google App engine pyobjc fail to install

Tags: python

i get this when i try to install pyobjc with easy-install

```
 sudo easy_install -U pyobjc
```

Searching for pyobjc
Best match: pyobjc 2.5.1
Processing pyobjc-2.5.1-py2.6.egg
pyobjc 2.5.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyobjc-2.5.1-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for pyobjc
Searching for pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement/
Reading http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net
Best match: pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement 2.5.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement/pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement-2.5.1.tar.gz#md5=0ec67fb8fae22104643d423a2b66ca17
Processing pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement-2.5.1.tar.gz
Running pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement-2.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-E_uAby/pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement-2.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-eOOIVp

```
 error: Installed distribution pyobjc-core 2.2b3 conflicts with requirement pyobjc-core>=2.5.1
```

please can you help me with this error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac Os X versions 10.7 and 10.8 you need this.

```
$ sudo env CC=clang easy_install -U pyobjc-core
$ sudo env CC=clang easy_install -U pyobjc
```

Comment: i m sorry i could not write you back before now but i had a lot of other works to do... i m trying your script right now :) i let you know if them are good :) i hope well